# Why cant RDS with mysql 8.0.23 doesn't allow to run window functions?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, mysql-8.0

I am using MySQL 8.0.23 on Amazon RDS.

innodb_version is 8.0.23
version is 8.0.23
Engine name as shown on RDS interface is My SQL Community

I can use CTE expression like "WITH" but when I try to use any window functions like the ones mentioned here : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html, it throws a error.  What am I missing ?

Works :

```
with items as ( 
   select number from item where updated_date > current_date 
) 
select * from items
```

Does not Work :

```
select number, row_number() from item
```

Error Message :

```
Query 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from item limit 1000' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mysql manual on [window function syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) says:

> MySQL also supports nonaggregate functions that are used only as window functions. For these, the OVER clause is mandatory

row_number() is included in this list, therefore you must provide an over clause. Fortunately, you can provide an empty over clause if you want your resultset to be the window, so the correct syntax will be:

```
with items as ( 
   select number, row_number() over() as rownumber from item where updated_date > current_date 
) 
select * from items
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out yesterday but forgot to update the thread here.